# Bootstrap 3 Multiple Nav bar Menus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using  this Bootstrap 3's example menu page for my site:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

When you shrink the page the menu at the top collapses into a single drop down list.

On my page I have two menues at the top left and right however when I shrink my page I don't get two drop down menues.

I would like it so that when I shrink the page I get two collapsed menues. Is this possible?

Comment: How is your navbar setup? Both left+right should collapse: http://bootply.com/78851

Comment: Hi your example is close to what I want but combines both left and right into one menu. I need two separate menus.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://bootply.com/79216 i add to button (different) target align the second menu to the right with `navbar-right` and add some css to reset the float and display of the navbars.

**html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex2-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex2-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

**css**

```
  .navbar-collapse:before, .navbar-collapse:after{display:inline; content:"";}
```