# Two navbars same row make collapse not work. How to make right nav disappear?

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get my navbar to collapse correctly.  I have three links on the right that should disappear when my navbar collapses.  Instead, they overlay the links I want to appear upon collapse.  Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
       <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
         <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
        <a href= "#" class="navbar-brand">XYZ</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#/projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#/finance">Finance</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#/resume">Resume</a></li>
       </ul>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/XYZ" class="icon-large icon-linked-in"></a> </li>
          <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/XYZ78" class="icon-large icon-twitter"></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.github.com/XYZ" class="icon-large icon-github"></a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

####UPDATED CODE, but icons collapse on new row overlaying content #######

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
        <a href= "#" class="navbar-brand"><a><img src="img/lior.jpeg"></a>
  </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="index.html#/projects">Projects</a></li>
             <li><a href="index.html#/finance">Finance</a></li>
             <li><a href="index.html#/resume">Resume</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div style="float:right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs hidden-md">
             <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/st" class="icon-large icon-linked-in"></a></li>
             <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/s" class="icon-large icon-twitter"></a></li>
             <li><a href="http://www.github.com/s" class="icon-large icon-github"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If I could make a suggestion - make use of free online services such as jsfiddle.net or bootply.com to enable others to quickly see your code, as well as visually show the problem. It makes it easier to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way seem to use the http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities.
For your right navigation (icons) use:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs hidden-md">
```

This will hide the icons when the navbar has been collapsed.

Also read: [Bootstrap 3 Multiple Nav bar Menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607062/bootstrap-3-multiple-nav-bar-menus/18643483)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I should have been clearer.  The right nav does disappear, but the icons on the right are super-imposed on my left-hand nav links when collapsed.  What I'd like is for those right <li>s to totally go away when collapsed (unless they can be forced to work well with the collapsed left-hand nav).

Comment: Remove the class  pull-left from your code. Consider to wrap your icons in a div with class `navbar-right` (and float the li without navbar classes)

Comment: I tried floating the LIs without the navbar classes, but without the navbar classes, the bullet lists show up.  I slightly re-edited based on some of your suggestions, and it collapses better now (right-hand icons collapse to the right), but the right-hand icons are not directly across from the left-side (way down).  It overlays on top of my content as a result.  I've updated my code to show you what I have.